# Ugly HTML list visible during page load, while waiting for JQuery tree plugin rendering

Tags: jquery, html, tree, render

I am using JQuery plugin named "jstree".
Such plugin is registered in the ready function, and is bound to a specific html div element.
So, obviously when the page is loaded, a raw ugly HTML list becomes a pretty tree, and the plugin works fine.

My problem is due to the fact that there is a phase (about one second) in which the raw HTML is visible in the page, waiting for the plugin to be triggered. In other words, there is a second in which it is perfectly visible an ugly HTML list. This beahviour is almost imperceptible with powerful PCs, but is
bothering on a normal machine.

How could I avoid such situation? Is there any way to render directly the tree list managed by the plugin, without making visible the ugly HTML (my customer is not very happy about such situation)?

Thanks

Comment: what about this: on page ready function do a `.hide()` for 1 seconds and then `.show()` it?

Comment: Or jsut set the tree hidden in its css and make it visible once jquery tree is loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be one approach but it may not be the best. First try hiding your list for 1 second using jQuery's function `.hide()` then show it back using jQuery's function `.show()`. Or you could(if possible) hide it from CSS then try a `.load()` function on your plugin and then `.show()` it thorugh jQuery.

Comment: The solution is correct. I hide the div when the ready function starts and I show the div when the load callback function of the plugin is called. But, I don't use "show" and "hide": I set css attribute "visibility" for preserving space.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't intend on the list being visible to people without JavaScript then can you not simply hide the list using CSS `display:none`. The plugin should still be able to pick it up, and render a pretty tree from your list, but your unstyled list will never be visible.